# ASP.NET MVC 4 example and IIS Express is too slow loading pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

My problem is that I've created an ASP.NET MVC 4 project in VS2013, and I haven't modified anything.

When I run the code, it takes a long time to get to the main page (Home), and I can understand that takes some time to load the symbols. But even when I'm in the homepage, moving through the About and Contact options are very slow, taking 10 seconds at least in load each option (or even 15 seconds).

Some of my mates when reach the Home page work smoothly, but not my case.

What can I do? I've tried to load Microsoft Symbols Servers in a Cache Symbols Directory, and the Enable Just My Code option is checked, I've even tried to reinstall Visual Studio... :S

The IIS 8 version is the default one installed with VS2013 Ultimate (I have Resharper installed what may cause even slower loads).

I know this is not exactly a code question, but maybe it implies some modification in it. Repeat, I create this kind of project with its default code.

Maybe VS2013 & IIS8 doesn't work properly on Windows 7? Maybe is resources problem? (I have 4GB Ram).

I'm currentyl working with VS2013, IIS8 & Entitiy Framework 4.5 (same happens with 4) in a PC with Windows 7, I7 2.36Ghz, and 4GB RAM.

Any advice is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What CPU and how much memory? Start perfmon before running, that will give you an idea where the problem may be. On a reasonably sized PC there are no noticeable delays post startup

Comment: I have to say that I've tried with VS2012 and works perfectly, I think the main problem is the IIS 8 and its compatibility with W7 or my PC. VS2012 uses ASP.NET Server which works from far faster. I will try your advices with VS2013 to find the issue and I'll comment the results. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What CPU and how much memory? Start perfmon before running, that will give you an idea where the problem may be. On a reasonably sized PC there are no noticeable delays post startup with visual studio 2012.

Comment: I have an I7 2.30 Ghz and 4GB Ram, with Windows 7 x64. I've checked that the reason why VS2012 and its server is faster is because of Cassini (the Default Server in VS2012 and before).
I'm wondering why IIS 8 is too slow in my PC, maybe is it optimized for Windows 8? Or I have any other issues that may cause this slowness.

Comment: I assume you mean iis 8 express and add another 4gb if you can

Comment: Yes, you are right IIS 8 EXPRESS ;) Ok I'll try to add 4GB more in these days, meanwhile I will work with VS2012, if it's a RAM problem I will validate your answer ;) Thanks !!